# Convert request.post to async/await

Tags: express, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have converted a lot of request.get to follow this new async/await pattern. Is there a way to do the same for request.post. Here's a sample code I have and would appreciate any input

```
 try {
request({ url: url, method: 'POST', body: parameters, json: true}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
    return res.status(200).send(response.body);
  } else {
      return res.status(500).send(response.body);
  }
});  
} catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think is there any difference between `get` and `post`? The exact same approach works on both. Please try it and show your attempt. Also you might want to post the code that you already converted to async/await.

Comment: Btw: `if (!error)` and `if (error) else` can never happen both.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry, that was a copy paste error. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the request method in a Promise and then in an async function like so:

```
let request = require('request');

async function asyncRequest(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => resolve({ error, response, body }));
  });
}

async function google() {
  let response = await asyncRequest('http://www.google.com');
  console.log(response.response.statusCode);
}

google();
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait) for `request`, you could use the `request-promise` module to avoid doing the Promise wrapping yourself